# Draw and write imagefile without Window

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I found that using `matplotlib` just to draw a diagram into a file is not as easy as it seems from reading the tutorials.
In the tutorials it is explained, that you just accumulate the data and then:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# ... fill variables with meaningful stuff
plt.plot(data.x,data.y,format_string)
plt.savefig(filename)
```

And done. That also works fine if you just execute it as a shell. But if you give this code to a process that doesn't have any window (like jenkins), then you just get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./to_graph.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
  File "./to_graph.py", line 78, in main
    plt.plot(warnings[0],warnings[1],args.format_warnings,label="Warnings")
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2460, in plot
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 701, in gca
    ax =  gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 369, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 343, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 80, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1688, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

The reason for this error, as I understand the sourcecode around the stack-trace lines, is that backend_tkagg.py expects to use an existing window (see the Tk.Tk() line in the stacktrace). So I wonder if there is a way to draw diagrams with matplotlib (or python at all) without relying on a window(-manager) to do the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a backend which will write directly to a file.

For details, see :
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

You need to call matplotlib.use before importing pyplot.

For instance :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("AGG")
import pyplot
# continue as usual
```

Actually, I just found out that this is also the solution given in the documentation :

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#generate-images-without-having-a-window-appear

Comment: Actually, you don't need to specify a backend.  The default works fine.

Comment: @cosmosis: Your comment is rather strange. It doesn't work fine, otherwise there wouldn't be this thread...

Comment: +1 as you need to set the backend in your script, if there is no suitable backend set in your `matplotlibrc`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'use'

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I also had this problem. Now I can use the images to generate Raspberry and save with pyplot unused variables in the graphical environment. Here's an example:

pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ cat testimgpython.py

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('AGG')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
senial = [2, 3, 5, 8, 20, 50, 100]
tiempo = range(len(senial))
plt.plot(tiempo, senial)
plt.savefig('/var/www/imageSimple1.png')
print 'Hecho!'
```